# Mapping class group.

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Recently I have been studing Mapping class group I know the mapping class group of genus 1 surface is $SL(2,Z)$ the a natural question is "What is the mapping class group of a genus three surface? "

Thanks

Comment: Probably You are going to find amusing that the genus three nonorientable compact surface has the same MCG.

Comment: What you are asking "what is", what do you really mean? Do you mean the formal definition? Are you asking for a list of properties? Do you mean an isomorphic to another group familiar to you? Do you mean an explicit presentation (as in Nick's answer?)?  Something totally different?

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 1 of "A SIMPLE PRESENTATION FOR
THE MAPPING CLASS GROUP
OF AN ORIENTABLE SURFACE " BRONISLAW WAJNRYB. ISRAEL JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS, Vol. 45, Nos. 2-3, 1983. Gives a presentation of the mapping class group of a closed orientable surface.

In the case of genus 3 the group is generated by 7 Dehn twists along certain curves on the surface. Wajnryb writes down a complete set of relations (which are quite long so I won't copy them here).